# Maps used online VS places in campaign mode

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

One big thing to do first in online mode is to well know the maps .

I know that I could walk and explore  in them alone in a private match. But it's boring...

I began to play the campaign mode to learn the places where the game is.

I only played about the half of the first mission and I didn't recognize a map that I've play on-line.

Does the on-line and campaign mode places are related  ?

If I continue to play in campaign  mode, will it help me to know maps used on-line ?

Will I be able to recognize some spots that I have to be aware like windows of building ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Maps in campaign are similar to ones in multiplayer, however, they are not even close to same. In multiplayer you want to know places where foes can hide and wait, snipping spots, choke points, alternative entrance points (both to building and areas) and so on. Most of them are specialy made for multiplayer mode.

Also, MW3 campain is very linear, which means that games itself leads you to next checkpoint. E.g. All side alley are somehow blocked, doors locked and so on. In multiplayer you don't want that. You want map where you can flank opposite team. You want safe house which has three and not one entrance and so on.

All in all, the best way to learn map is to play it online. Just walking around map won't teach you anything. For example, by just walking around the map in private match you could learn that on spot X is a box, but only in real battle (multiplayer) you will learn that that box is famous spot for shotgun camper.